# PHP Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_PORT in /xxx/xxx/xxx/domain.com/public_html/system/startup.php on line 59

Tags: php, cron, opencart2.x

i am having trouble with my open-cart site. I want to run a cron-job thru direct-admin. and i get this in my email:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SERVER_PORT in
>   /xxx/xxx/xxx/domain.com/public_html/system/startup.php on line 59

the code:

```
// Check if SSL
if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '1'))) || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = true;
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https' || !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == 'on') {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = true;
} else {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = false;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: You don't give much information about your cron job but `SERVER_PORT` (together with some other keys form `$_SERVER`) does not make sense in the command line thus doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in opencart code in system/startup.php.
You can see an open issue [here](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/5128)

Following solution did work for me:
change line

```
if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '1'))) || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
```

with

```
if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '1'))) || (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)) {
```

It's better if you do this using [vqmod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart) so you don't change the core file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the real problem is that the command is called from cron and not from your web server (which would fill the `_SERVER` array). In the PHP file, all other keys except `SERVER_PORT` (like e.g. `_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`) are filled with reasonable values if not set.

Try adding the following lines before the offending one (59):

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'])) {
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = getenv('SERVER_PORT');
}
```

and define `SERVER_PORT` as an environment variable before running the PHP command. If your port is always `80` or `443`, you could also set it directly instead of getting it from the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Change this `if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '1'))) || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {`

to this:

`if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '1'))) || (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'])) && ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)) {`

Explanation: Seems like on your `$_SERVER` array, `SERVER_PORT` is not available - so PHP is showing a notice. You can fix it by checking if the key exists in the array before checking if the value is equal to 443.

Comment: Hello Muhammad,

I replaced it. Now i get the following error.:


PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /xxx/xxx/xxx/domain.com/public_html/system/system/startup.php on line 59

Comment: Hello Muhammad, thanks for the reply again, when i replace the code, the entire website is not working anymore. So i think this is also not working.